# Como iniciar una AppCompatActivity desde un Fragment

Tags: java, android-studio, android-fragment, activity, android-intent

Tengo 2 clases que extienden de un Fragment y un AppCompatActivity y mi problema es que desde la clase Fragment quiero iniciar la AppCompatActivity e intentado iniciar la activity por medio de un boton de la siguiente forma

```
btnAddRes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            System.out.println("Funciona");//lo use para verificar que estuviera entrando al clickListener
            Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityRegistra.class);
            startActivity(detail);
        }
    });
```

pero mi aplicacion se cierra al momento de querer pasar del fragment al activity

Comment: Hola Juan, tu código es correcto, lo que estas realizando debería funcionar, pero **las causas por las cuales se cierre pueden ser diversas, si quieres desarrollar en Android el uso del LogCat es indispensable, ¿que error se muestra en el LogCat?**

Answer (score 0):

Para abrir una actividad inicialmente tenes que declararla cómo default y launcher activity en tu manifest. Esa actividad puede abrir un Fragmento. Si tenes una 2nda Actividad que querés abrir desde un fragmento podes hacerlo de la forma que tenés en tu onClickListener. Tené en cuenta que todas las actividades deben estar declaradas en tu manifest.

manifest:

```
 <application...>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myproject.view.activity.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myproject.view.activity.ActivityRegistra">
        ...
    </activity>
</aplication>
```

MainActivity.java

```
@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Fragment newFragment = new MyFragment();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);

    transaction.commit();
}
```

MyFragment.java

```
btnAddRes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
         Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(), ActivityRegistra.class);
         startActivity(intent);
     }
});
```

Eso debería funcionar.
Te recomiendo que también investigues Kotlin, tiene formas más sencillas de interactuar entre fragmentos y actividades, en mi opinión es un lenguaje más sencillo de aprender y mucho más poderoso que Java. También investigá sobre Navigation y JetPack sobre librerías androidX el resto se puede decir que está quedando obsoleto.

Comment: Hola ¿porque comentas que tiene un concepto errado?, en su código se muestra que abre la Activity usando desde el fragmento la Activity que lo contiene.

Comment: Tenés razón, me quedé en el tiempo con el concepto de startActivity cómo parte de Context. En androidx startActivity ya s encuentra también dentro de Fragment, aunque con la restricción que el Fragment esté adjunto a una Actividad. Así que técnicamente mi respuesta hoy está herrada ya la actualizo.